# gdb - cygexpat-1.dll missing

Tags: c, gdb, cygwin, gnu

My question is about the gdb (Gnu Debugger)
on the cmd when I type gdb --version i get an error:

The program cant start because cygexpact-1.dll is missing from your computer. Try re-installing the program to fix this problem.

I re-installed the gdb but didnt solve the problem !

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Install libexpat1 which is under Libs